# How to create a new collectionView when switching to another calendarView

Tags: swift, xcode

I am having trouble trying to create a new collection view. I want to effectively have a collectionView with unique properties and then when I click on a date in my view controller it changes to a effectively a blank collectionView template so that the user can then put it there recipes.

How would I go about changing the collectionView (when user clicked on a date), change to a collection-view template and then save when the user puts in data?

Here is the code for the controller along with a picture example:

```
import UIKit
import GCCalendar


class CalendarViewController123: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    // MARK: Properties

    fileprivate var calendarView: GCCalendarView!

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    @IBOutlet weak var datelabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var open: UIBarButtonItem!

    @IBAction func trytoday(_ sender: Any) {

     self.calendarView.select(date: Date())
    }
    }

// MARK: - View

extension CalendarViewController123 {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        open.target = revealViewController()
        open.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))

        self.addToolbar()
        self.addCalendarView()
        self.addConstraints()

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for:.default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()

    }
}

// MARK: - Toolbar

extension CalendarViewController123 {

    fileprivate func addToolbar() {

        self.navigationController!.isToolbarHidden = false

        let space = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let displayMode = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Display Mode", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.displayMode))

        self.toolbarItems = [ space, displayMode]
    }


    @objc func displayMode() {

        self.calendarView.displayMode = (self.calendarView.displayMode == .month) ? .week : .month
    }

}


// MARK: - Calendar View

fileprivate extension CalendarViewController123 {

    func addCalendarView() {

        self.calendarView = GCCalendarView()

        self.calendarView.delegate = self
        self.calendarView.displayMode = .week


        self.calendarView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.view.addSubview(self.calendarView)
    }
}

// MARK: - Constraints

fileprivate extension CalendarViewController123 {

    func addConstraints() {

        self.calendarView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 2).isActive = true
        self.calendarView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        self.calendarView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        self.calendarView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 325).isActive = true
    }
}

// MARK: - GCCalendarViewDelegate

extension CalendarViewController123: GCCalendarViewDelegate {

    func calendarView(_ calendarView: GCCalendarView, didSelectDate date: Date, inCalendar calendar: Calendar) {

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

        dateFormatter.calendar = calendar
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: "MMM dd", options: 0, locale: calendar.locale)
        //yyyy
      //  self.navigationItem.title = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

self.datelabel.text = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    }
}
```

[image]

The Green is the collectionView on a view controller

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what data you are showing and how you are retrieving it. If you can provide more information I will update my answer accordingly.

**1. Select Date**

```
@IBAction func trytoday(_ sender: Any) {
    self.calendarView.select(date: Date())
    self.fetchData(forDate: selectedDate)
}
```

**2. Fetch Data**

```
func fetchData(forDate date: Date) {
    //Fetch data and return array of objects
    self.objects = retreivedObjects
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

**3. Load Data**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return objects.count
}
```

**4. Setup Cell with Data**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? Cell else { return UICollectionViewCell}
    cell.configure(withObject: objects[indexPath.item])
    return cell
}
```

Comment: I here thank you so much for getting back, essentially there is going to be a plus button that allows the user to go to another controller to choose a recipe and then when the user goes back it will update with the collection view of recipes. I am just try to find out how to select different dates and there would be a blank collection view so the user can put recipes in for that specific day